# Is it possible to override gutter-styles in certain contexts in Singularity to get fixed gutters?

Tags: css, singularitygs

I have a matrix of images. Each row 2 images, one a width of 1/3 the other 2/3 and a gutter in between the two. All the images have the exact same height. But if reduce the viewport width at certain viewports the 2/3 image gets smaller in height than the 1/3 image. I suspect that it is due to the default gutter-style i use in this particular case. In all other occasions it behaves fine but maybe here it is the root of the problem.

My grid settings are:

```
$grids: 6;
$grids: add-grid(9 at 675px);
$grids: add-grid(12 at 850px);
$grids: add-grid(15 at 1075px);
$grids: add-grid(18 at 1200px);
$gutters: 1/3;
$output:'isolation';
```

and a sample part of the css looks that way ( i have 3 more of those switch-baseline includes):

```
@include switch-baseline($baseline850, $vr-850...) {
    &:nth-child(4n+1) {
        @include isolation-span(4, 1, 'right', $gutter:.5);
    }
    &:nth-child(4n+4) {
        @include isolation-span(4, 9, 'right');
    }
    &:nth-child(4n+2) {
        @include isolation-span(8, 5, 'right');
    }
    &:nth-child(4n+3) {
        @include isolation-span(8, 1, 'right', $gutter:.5);
    }
    &:last-child {
        @include trailer(2);
    }
}
```

Now my question is, would it be possible to override the default gridsettings for a single mixin or layout context? I've tried $gutter-styles: fixed after $gutter:.5 as well as add the gutter-styles statement to the layout mixin - both lead to an compass error. i am using singularity 1.1.2 . best regards ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! You can either pass `$gutter-style` to your `grid-span` call, or `$gutter-style` to the `@layout` mixin. See the [Context Overrides](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Spanning-The-Grid#wiki-context-overrides) section of the documentation.

Comment: Actually i already looked into the context overrides section before i've posted my question on here but i was only able to find $grid, $gutter and $output-style listed in the text and examples - no sign of $gutter-style there. I am even unable to find it with cmd f if i look for "gutter-st" on the context overrides page. :s

Comment: and i've retried to add ```$gutter-styles: 'fixed'``` to the grid-span, isolation-span and the layout mixin but all returned again that the mixin doesn't have an argument named $gutter-styles.

Comment: ```$gutter-style``` is also unknown as argument.

Comment: What version of Singularity are you using?

Comment: Singularity 1.2.0 resolves this issue, but there are a handful of changes that aren't yet updated in the the docs (but are in the CHANGELOG)

Comment: Ah saw it now. Cool. I read correctly that Singularity only relies onto Sass 3.3 as dependency and Compass isn't necessary anymore? I wanted to wait with the installation of Sass and Compass until the final versions are out. But if Singularity only needs Sass i might just install that for now. Cool thanks!

Comment: Yup, only needs a compiler that is compatible with Sass 3.3

Comment: ok then i will give it a spin this weekend. thanks! But still uncertain if this will fix my differing heights issue (the initial reason i looked for $gutter-styles in the first place). probably i will post a follow up question later today. it's a tricky one, but i need to investigate and test a bit more beforehand.